# angular2 - a loading progressbar for the main page (while angular itself is loading)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, loader, angular-http-interceptors

is it possible to make a loader progressbar (or  just percentage text) in the index.html that tells the percentage of the loading?
I think it will be done with JS not angular2 (since its not loaded yet) but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to do it .

index.html

```
<my-app>
  <div class="loading-container">
    <div class="loading-title">Loading (x %)</div>
  </div>
</my-app>
```

Comment: You can create a Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen as this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm

Comment: thank you I'll give it a try